# C# Serializing datacontracts from file

Tags: c#, filestream, datacontractserializer

I have a list of Xml messages specifically DataContract messages that i record to a file. And i am trying to deserialize them from file one by one. I do not want to read the whole file into memory at once because i expect it to be very big.

I have an implementation of this serialization and that works. I did this by serializing using a FileStream and reading the bytes and using regular expression to determine the end of element. Then taking the element and using DataContractSerializer to get the actual object.

But i was told I should be using higher level code to do this task and it seems like that should be possible. I have the following code that i think should work but it doesn't.

```
FileStream readStream = File.OpenRead(filename);
DataContractSerializer ds = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MessageType));
MessageType msg;
while ((msg = (MessageType)ds.ReadObject(readStream)) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test " + msg.Property1);
}
```

The above code is fed with an input file containing something along the following lines:

```
<MessageType>....</MessageType>
<MessageType>....</MessageType>
<MessageType>....</MessageType>
```

It appears that i can read and deserialize the first element correctly but after that it fails saying:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException was unhandled
  Message=There was an error deserializing the object of type MessageType. The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
  Source=System.Runtime.Serialization
```

I have read somewhere that it is due to the way DataContractSerializer works with padded '\0''s to the end - but i couldn't figure out how to fix this problem when reading from a stream without figuring out the end of MessageType tag in some other way. Is there another Serialization class that i should be using? or perhaps a way around this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you're deserializing the data from the file, WCF uses by default a reader which can only consume proper XML documents. The document which you're reading isn't - it contains multiple root elements, so it's effectively a *fragment*. You can change the reader the serializer is using by using another overload of `ReadObject`, as shown in the example below, to one which accepts fragments (by using the `XmlReaderSettings` object). Or you can have some sort of wrapping element around the `<MessageType>` elements, and you'd read until the reader were positioned at the end element for the wrapper.

```
public class StackOverflow_7760551
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Person[Name={0},Age={1}]", this.Name, this.Age);
        }
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        const string fileName = "test.xml";
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
        {
            Person[] people = new Person[]
            { 
                new Person { Name = "John", Age = 33 },
                new Person { Name = "Jane", Age = 28 },
                new Person { Name = "Jack", Age = 23 }
            };

            foreach (Person p in people)
            {
                XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings
                {
                    Indent = true,
                    IndentChars = "  ",
                    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
                    Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false),
                    CloseOutput = false,
                };
                using (XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(fs, ws))
                {
                    DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person));
                    dcs.WriteObject(w, p);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(fileName));

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName))
        {
            XmlReaderSettings rs = new XmlReaderSettings
            {
                ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment,
            };
            XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(fs, rs);
            while (!r.EOF)
            {
                Person p = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person)).ReadObject(r) as Person;
                Console.WriteLine(p);
            }
        }

        File.Delete(fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Reusable things should be created outside your loops (XmlWriterSettings, DataContractSerializer), but good answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your file contains [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) 
It's common for UTF-8 encoding

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MessageType));
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(stream);
foreach(XmlElement elm in xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("MessageType"))
{
    MessageType mt = (MessageType)xml.Deserialize(new StringReader(elm.OuterXml)); 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't xdoc.Load(stream) load the entire file into memory? If so, I don't want to do that. My file can run up to 10-20 Gbs ..

Comment: I am not sure. If so, you can try XmlReader